# Scripting Bridge and com.apple.iWork.Pages -- can this work?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, applescript

I am trying to count the words in Pages document (the doc format is RTF) using the scripting bridge.  (I *can* do it using NSApplescript but I would rather not have all the applescript-aware duct tape in my code)
When I perform this task using applescript (and NSAppleScript APIs) I can do this very simply (and successfully):

```
on wordCount(appName,docName)
local mydoc
local wordcount
tell application appName
    set mydoc to document docName
    set wordcount to count of words of mydoc
    log "wordcount = " & wordcount
    return wordcount
end tell
end wordCount
```

However when I try the equivalent using the scripting bridge all my objects seem to have null contents.  My code is as follows:

```
+ (NSUInteger) wordCountForApp: (SBApplication*) sbApp docNamed: (NSString*) docName
{
    PagesApplication *pages = (PagesApplication*)sbApp; 
    PagesDocument *doc = [[pages documents] objectWithName:docName];
    PagesText *text = [doc bodyText];
    SBElementArray *words = [text words];
    NSUInteger wc = [words count];
    NSLog(@"Pages word count = %ul", (unsigned int) wc);
    return wc; // wc comes back as zero always ... grrrr
}
```

I have verified that I am running this stuff on the main thread (and that equivalent code works against TextEdit).  Any ideas as to what is going on/how to work around?

Thanks for having read this far....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was that I was asking for a document named "something.rtf" that I had just opened in Pages. But when Pages opens "something.rtf" it names it "something". And then when you ask for document named "something.rtf" it does not return nil because the document does not exist by that *name*. Instead, it returns a PagesDocument named "something.rtf" which has no valid contents: a NIL document. Which I guess I just was too stupid to recognize when I submitted to SO.

I have since checked other apps and this seems to be normal applescript behavior when you ask for a document by name (to get back a "valid object" containing a NIL document) oh well.

Answer (score 3):

That code works for me.  The equivalent in F-Script:

```
> pages := SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier: 'com.apple.iWork.Pages'

> (pages documents objectWithName: 'fun') bodyText words count
303
```

I'd suggest you step through it with a debugger and make sure that each object is what you're expecting, i.e. `pages`, `[pages documents]`, etc.

If you're writing this code for external use, ideally you should not refer to documents by name; the user may have multiple documents with the same name open.

Another option is [objc-appscript](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/objc-appscript/), which provides an neat ASTranslate utility that transforms AppleScript into Objective-C (or Ruby or Python for the other appscript bindings).  For example, for the above, you'd have something like:

```
#import "PGGlue/PGGlue.h"
PGApplication *pages = [PGApplication applicationWithName: @"Pages"];
PGReference *ref = [[pages documents] byName: @"fun"];
PGCountCommand *cmd = [[ref count] each: [PGConstant word]];
id result = [cmd send];
```

Comment: Something strange is going on definitely -- its just the bridge code that fails and it only fails for Pages (that I know of).  I may have to package up a demo and try it on another mac to see if mine is somehow "possessed".  I have stepped through the debugger and the objects come back but they are null on the inside somehow (according to [NSObject description] anyway). As regards the doc naming issue it would not be a problem in the context of this code.  Anyway, all that as it may be, I was unaware of either of the tools you brought to my attention, thanks for that. Off to investigate...

Comment: So the problem was that I was asking for a document named "something.rtf".  And Pages opens "something.rtf" but *names* it "something".  And then when you ask for document named "something.rtf" it does not return nil because the document does not exist by that name.  Instead, it returns a PagesDocument named "something.rtf" which has no valid contents: a NIL document.  Which I guess I just was too stupid to recognize when I submitted to SO.  I have since checked other apps and this seems to be normal applescript behavior when you ask for a document by name (to get a nil document)  oh well.

Comment: Yeah, there's a distinction between a display name of a document (which can have extensions stripped, or even a localized name) and the name on disk.  You might want to match by path instead.